# User not authenticated but here

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I authenticate users from a database through my own login form. Everything seems to work fine but when, after entering the good username and the good password, I arrive on the home page, I can see, in Symfony toolbar, that the user is not really authenticated (it is yellow, I have the array of roles, the username and Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken class) but authenticated is NO.

What do I miss to finish this authentication ?

Thank you

Comment: can you put some code

Comment: Please provide some code (especially the part where you create the token for the user is important).

Comment: no code to create the token.. I use the symfony UsernamePasswordToken . It is in the library and called automatically after the login_check

Comment: I just have my user class and my provider.. that's it

Comment: use [Guard](https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/guard). It simplifies things enormously.  (You dont need a knp subscription to view the transcript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Maybe it can help someone.

To fully authenticate the use you have some rules to add access_control in the secureity.yml file and everything is fine like:

```
- { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: I cannot check now, but I don't believe in that.